# Is it possible to access the arguments of the failed method in RetryListener?

Tags: java, spring-retry

I have a method that takes a session object to talk to an external system. The session object contains a username and a session token. If the external system doesn't recognize the session token then an exception is thrown. In that case  I want to login with the passed username, create a new session object and call the original method with the new session object containing a valid session token.

I created a Listener extending RetryListenerSupport. I annotated the method with @Retry and specified my listener as listener. But in the onError method of my listener I can not access the arguments of the method.

```java
@Value
public class Session {
    private final String username;
    private final String sessionToken;
}

@Component
public class EmployeeRetryListener extends RetryListenerSupport {
    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context,
                                                 RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        if (throwable instance of UnknownSessionException) {
            // Here I want to access the arguments of the createEmployee method
        }
        super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
    }

}

@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Retryable(listeners = "employeeRetryListener")
    public void createEmployee(Session session, String employeeName) throws UnknownSessionException {
    }
}
```

I want to know the username in the Session instance with which the method is called. And I also want to modify the Session instance to update to sessionToken.

Comment: have you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [RetryTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html#retryTemplate) instead of `@Retryable` annotation. 
With template you can access `RetryContext` and set your arguments manually:

```java
private String goSomething(String arg1) {
    return retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
        context.setAttribute("argument1", "arg1");
        return "some result"
    });
}
```

And then you can access this argument in your listener:

```java
@Override
public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
    if (throwable instance of UnknownSessionException) {
        String arg1 = (String) context.getAttribute("argument1")
    }
    super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be needing the @Recover annotation on specific exception. As the name suggests, the retry would just redo the failed operation. However the recover method will give you options to do specific things in code while you recover an error. This also allows access to the parameters of the method being "retried".

[Spring Recover documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Recover.html).

[Retry with Recover guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry).

Look at section 4.2 in link 2. It has examples on using retry with recover